# Understanding $Ax = b$ in terms of $Ax$ by columns and $Ax$ by rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

My question arises from an excerpt from Chapter 1.4 of Gilbert Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications".

Strang illustrates a few points on the titular concept of this post using the following matrix $A$ and vector $x$.

$$A=\ 
        \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 6 \\
        3 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$x=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2  \\
        5 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

He notes that the standard method, elementary of matrix multiplication, namely $Ax$ by rows, is a valid operation because it recreates the original system of linear equations arising from this problem, thus maintaining an equality.

This method creates this solution:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
5 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\hat i + \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
5 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\hat j + \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
5 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\hat k 
$$

Whilst the $Ax$ by columns, interpretation, which, I am guessing, has the $\hat i, \hat j$ and $\hat k$ components of $x$ scale the set of $\hat i, \hat j$ and $\hat k$ components of matrix $A$ produces:

$$2\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 3\\ 1 \end{array} \right)+ 5\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 0\\ 1 \end{array} \right)+ 0\left( \begin{array}{c}
6 \\ 3\\ 7 \end{array} \right).$$

Both should produce the vector $b= 7\hat i + 6\hat j + 7\hat k$, but I'm a bit confused as to how the $Ax$ by rows algorithm makes sense. For example, the row $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ describes the $LHS$ of a plane equation in $R^3$. Why would treating *this* as a vector, and multiplying it by $x$ produce the $\hat i$ scalar of $b$? And why can we define a vector as a column *or* a row of a matrix? It seems odd that a $3x3$ matrix can have $2$ different sets of vectors yet still describe the same matrix.

Comment: Well, because each of those entries is the first component of each corresponding column of $A$. And the more fundamental thing is that $Ax=\sum_j x_j a_j$ where $a_j$ are the columns. Thus $(Ax)_1=\sum_j x_j a_{1j}$ by just restricting attention to the first components of the $a_j$. Also, have you looked at linear algebra before? If so, I'd advise you to skip chapter 1 and read chapter 2. If not, I might advise a different first reference, Strang's chapter 1 is not that great IMO.

Comment: @Ian Do you have any recommendations? I've dabbled in linear algebra, but not looked at matrices very in depth.

Comment: I mean if you've gone through a first course in the subject then you should be fine. But if not then I'd advise a more traditional book like David Lay's book to get you started. You don't have to go through the whole thing, something like the first 2-3 chapters of Lay subsumes Chapter 1 of Strang. Chapter 1 of Strang is worth reading to get his perspective, but you really have to be able to cleanly see things like, say, $Ax=\sum_j x_j a_j$ without needing to think about it to appreciate that perspective.

Comment: @Ian I see. I, for instance, am very used to solving $Ax=b$ but I've never had it explained to me in such a detail before. So, hopefully I'm prepared enough for this textbook,  but I appreciate the input and I'll consider your recommendation :).

Comment: I'd recommend seeing the video lectures on OCW by Strang. Also, for your questions I'd suggest looking further into the four fundamental subspaces: The column space, row space, null space and left null space

Comment: @AbuBakr This is still Chapter 1. The fundamental subspaces are in chapter 2.